# SDL Tridion 2011 - Unable to add parent publications

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a problem with my development VM with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 installed on it.

When I add a new publication, I cannot add an existing Publication as a parent and so I am unable to create a BluePrint hierarchy.

The add Publication button flashes up the dialog but then it disappears.

Each Publication seems to be created in its own BluePrint hierarchy..

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Did you create a root structure group in the parent publication?

Comment: This was the problem - if you answer this, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a root structure group before you can use a publication as a parent publication.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this scenario, but that was happened cause of Chrome browser only, Have you tried this in IE?

Comment: Thanks for your response - it was caused by the lack of a root structure group.